# help me understand why this question was closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions

[is this javascript property defaulting pattern a code smell?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/181550/is-this-javascript-property-defaulting-pattern-horrible) is the question at, um, question.

I'm not upset or offended by the closure; no ego involved here, and I got the feedback I needed before the question was closed anyway, but in the interests of being a good citizen I'd like to understand why folks considered this to be off-topic.  Given the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq), this seems to be clearly in the realm of a design pattern question and thus on-topic.

I suppose it could be considered to be an implementation question (and thus more suited for Overflow) but when I asked it I was really asking about the pattern (as the question title indicates) not a specific implementation.

Comment: Agreed, at first read this one seems like an incorrect closure. I don't have time right now to give it a closer look, will revisit tomorrow and if there isn't an answer here explaining how it's off topic (or hasn't been re-opened) I will re-open it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't even speculate why this was closed by the community, and usually I try to defend their position when they close a question.

I reopened your question.

Comment: This is only a guess, but I think this is one of these cases where the first close voter misread the question, and the rest of the close voters didn't pay much attention to it. It's a side-effect of `/review` that we've been seeing _a lot_ on Stack Overflow, but not on Programmers. Let's hope this doesn't become a thing here as well. That said, incorrect closures happen, I've made quite a few myself.

Answer (score 2):

I could see how an argument could be made that your question was more implementationy(?) than theoretical and therefore would possibly fit better on SO or code review maybe. I wouldn't vote that way, but I could understand that line of reasoning.

Comment: Sure, what worried me though is that it wasn't migrated. I can understand people reading it as an implementation question, but that should have translated to migration votes, not off topic votes. Unless of course the close voters thought it would fit Code Review, which we don't have a migration path for (but if that was the case, why no flags?).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not asking "Is this pattern a good idea?" your question (in essence) is "dose this pattern indicate that I have done something wrong [at a deeper level]". Furthermore, you ask your question fully in light of your own code, and your project. While this isn't a bad thing, it would be more relevant on SO or CR.

The same question could be asked in a more generalized way, that would be both on topic, as well as generally more useful to anyone else who may have the same question in the future.

Comment: If you feel that the question could be rewritten in a way that would make it a bit more generalized or emphasize that it's indeed a conceptual question and not a technical one, go ahead and edit it.